# kernel is not giving expected results for each core

Tags: kernel, opencl

I am in the learning phase of OpenCl.

**Problem** : create two arrays : input and output of 50 elements initialized with value "-1".

I am passing both arrays as input and output buffers to GPU and solving (incrementing each element of array) for 5 iterations. Hence,
all elements' value should increase to 4. As, i am dividing this job in 10 cores by

```
size_t global_work_size[1] = {10};
```

and my kernel is solving all the arrays according to get_global_id(0) value, which means, solving each 5 elements in each core.

So, my final output should be:

```
output[0] = 4.0000
output[1] = 4.0000
...
...
output[48] = 4.0000
output[49] = 4.0000
```

But, my Output is coming:

```
output[0] = 9.0000
output[1] = 9.0000
output[2] = 9.0000
output[3] = 9.0000
output[4] = 9.0000
output[5] = 4.0000
output[6] = 4.0000
output[7] = 4.0000
output[8] = 4.0000
output[9] = 4.0000
...
...
output[48] = 4.0000
output[49] = 4.0000
```

As we can see, difference in output is for first 10 elements. This might come because, my kernel for first core is running twice.
But, i couldn't understand the exact reason. Please suggest me, where i am going wrong? Might be logic is wrong, or am i missing a big thing thing in OpenCl?

**program.c** file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

#define MEM_SIZE (50)
#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)

int main() {
    float input[MEM_SIZE], output[MEM_SIZE];
    int go, i;
    for (i = 0; i < MEM_SIZE; i++) {
        input[i] = -1.0;
        output[i] = -1.0;
    }
    FILE *fp;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_context context = NULL;
    cl_command_queue command_queue = NULL;
    cl_program program = NULL;
    cl_kernel kernel = NULL;
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret;
    size_t source_size;
    cl_event event;
    char *source_str;
    fp = fopen("algebra.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    /*Initialization*/
    /* Get Platform and Device Info */
    ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    /* Create OpenCL context */
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    /* Create Command Queue */
    command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    /*Initialization complete*/

    cl_mem inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(float),(void *) input, NULL);
    cl_mem outputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY , MEM_SIZE * sizeof(float), NULL, NULL);



    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue,
                                  inputBuffer,
                                  CL_FALSE,
                                  0,
                                  MEM_SIZE * sizeof(float),
                                  input,
                                  0,
                                  NULL,
                                  &event);
    ret = clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
    clReleaseEvent(event);

    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue,
                                  outputBuffer,
                                  CL_FALSE,
                                  0,
                                  MEM_SIZE * sizeof(float),
                                  output,
                                  0,
                                  NULL,
                                  &event);

    ret = clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
    clReleaseEvent(event);

    /* Create Kernel Program from the source */
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str,(const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

    /* Build Kernel Program */
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    /* Create OpenCL Kernel */
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "calc", &ret);

    /* Set OpenCL Kernel Parameters */
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&inputBuffer);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&outputBuffer);

    /* Execute OpenCL Kernel*/
    ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel, 0, NULL,NULL);
    double io;
    size_t global_work_size[1] = {10};
    inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(float),(void *) output, NULL);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&inputBuffer);
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, outputBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(float), output, 0, NULL, NULL);

    for (go = 0; go < MEM_SIZE; go++) {
        printf("output[%d] = %f\n", go, output[go]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    /* Finalization */
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(inputBuffer);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(outputBuffer);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
    return 1;
}
```

**algebra.cl** (kernel file):

```
__kernel void euler(__global float* in, __global float* out)
{
    int idx = get_global_id(0) * 5;
    int end_idx = idx + 5;
    double j = 0;
    int i;
    while (j < 5.0) {
        j++;
        for (i = idx; i < end_idx; i++) {
            out[i] = out[i] + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

gcc compilation:

```
gcc program.c -o test -l OpenCL -I /usr/local/opencl/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-RC-lnx32/include/ -L /usr/local/opencl/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-RC-lnx32/lib/x86
```

Comment: is this statement correct out[i] = out[i] + 1; ? also what is 10000 used for.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @SagarKotecha. I posted the wrong code. Updated correct one. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a completely wrong understanding of what you are doing, so, you are expecting a behavior that will never happen.

1. `clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel, 0, NULL,NULL);` This will run the kernel only with 1 work item, so, yes. The first work-item is being run twice. That is your main problem.
2. `size_t global_work_size[1] = {10};` Does mean 10 work-items indeed. But this is not the way of working with OpenCL. You should never put 10M of items to process and run 10 work-items. You should put 10M of items to process and as many work-items as you can (ie: 10M as well, `1 work-item -> 1 simple action`), otherwise the GPU will be 99% idle. In addition, this will be easier to understand and program, since you will almost have no loops in your kernel code.
3. Generally you should not reuse output, or increment output values `out[i] = out[i] +1;`. Since if many work-items change the same value it may lead to race conditions or wrong results. remember, all the work-items may be running at the same time and independently.

Comment: And yes @DarkZeros clEnqueueTask is added twice, as it was added while debugging the different issues of the code and i forgot to remove it later. That totally solves my problem. But, as i had updated my code properly now... except clEnqueueTask issue, is there any place else i am going wrong?

Comment: Well, I would recomend you that if you really want to do (in the final real implementation) an operation that consists of ie: 200M operations. Then you should run 200M work-items. The scheduler will take care of it. (I updated my answer). Apart from that, I have no other real suggestion unles you specify exactly what do you want to do with OpenCL.